# Can I install Multiple Magento Extensions at the same time ( 1.9 )

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to do a server upgrade from 1.3 -> 1.9 . I have all new extensions to install - can I just disable the cache / compiler and copy all the files? ( there would be around 10 new extensions ) - or do I need to install them one by one ; logging in and out of the admin panel each time.

thanks :-)
Marty

Comment: Where it stinks is if two database installers collide. If you're following proper Magento practice, you will have a DEV server where you test this out. Running Virtual Box and a Linux VM takes few resources. 1.3 to 1.9 is a horrible step to do first on a live server BTDT, TEE SHIRT STINKS.

Comment: Of course this is programming related.  Magento is an e-commerce platform - when you install an extension - it runs a script.

Comment: Thanks.  I would have hoped that if you copy the files , it would do them in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install multiple extension at the same time. But Good approach is installing extension one by one. After install each extension, check its functionality and install another.

If any extension generates any error, By this way it help you to identify particular extension. Instead of checking for all 10 extensions.